# Select dinámico php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3, select

tengo un problema al querer cargar un select desde otro select.

Tengo mi controlador:

```
<?php  
class HomeController extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form'); //Helper necesario para crear un form
        $this->load->helper('url'); //Helper necesario para poder interactuar entre acciones
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('ValidadorRut');
        $this->load->model('consultas_model','CM',true);
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $regiones['Regiones'] = $this->CM->get_regiones();
        $this->load->view('formularioView.php',$regiones);
    }

    public function buscar_ciudad()
    {
        $NumeroRegion = $this->input->post('region');

        echo "Holaaaa";

        if($NumeroRegion){
            $ciudades = $this->CM->get_ciudades($NumeroRegion);
            foreach ($ciudades as $fila) {
                echo '<option value="'.$fila['IdCiudad'].'">'.$fila['Nombre'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="0">Seleccione ciudad...</option>';
        }
    }

    public function validar()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('idNombres', 'Nombres', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('idAP', 'AP', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('idAM', 'AM', 'required');

        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Esta es mi modelo:

```
<?php

class Consultas_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();
    }

    public function get_regiones()
    {
        $resultado = $this->db->get('region');
        $tabla_regiones = $resultado->result_array();
        return $tabla_regiones;
    }

    public function get_ciudades($NumeroRegion)
    {
        $this->db->where('NumeroRegion', $NumeroRegion);
        $this->db->order_by('Nombre','asc');
        $resultado = $this->db->get('ciudad');
        $tabla_ciudades = $resultado->result_array();

        return $tabla_ciudades;
    }
}
```

Y esta es mi vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#region").change(function() {
                $("#region option:selected").each(function() {
                    region = $('#region').val();
                    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/HomeController/buscar_ciudad", {
                        region : region
                    }, function(data) {
                        $("#ciudad").html(data);
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body background="Fondo.jpg">
    <div class="container" style="width:50%">
        <h2>Ingreso de clientes</h2>

        <?= form_open(base_url().'index.php/HomeController/validar', array( //De esta manera creamos una etiqueta FORM en html
        'name'=>'mi_formulario','id' => 'form','method' => 'POST'));?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= form_label(/*VALUE=*/'Nombres:',/*NAME=*/'Nombres'); ?><br>
            <?= form_input(/*name*/'Nombres',/*label*/'',/*mochila*/'class="form-control id="Nombres" placeholder="Ingrese nombres..."')?><br>

            <?= form_label(/*VALUE=*/'Apellido paterno:',/*NAME=*/'APaterno'); ?><br>
            <?= form_input('ApellidoP','','class="form-control" id="ApellidoP" placeholder="Ingrese apellido paterno..."')?><br>

            <?= form_label(/*VALUE=*/'Apellido materno:',/*NAME=*/'AMaterno'); ?><br>
            <?= form_input('ApellidoM','','class="form-control" id="ApellidoM" placeholder="Ingrese apellido materno..."')?><br>

            <?= form_label('Rut:','Rut'); ?><br>
            <?= form_input('Rut','','class="form-control" placeholder="Ej:18745962-8"')?><br>
            <?= form_label('Region :','Region'); ?>
            <select class="form-control" id="region" Name="region">
                <option value="0">Seleccione región...</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($Regiones as $fila) {
                        echo'<option value="'.$fila['NumeroRegion'].'">'.$fila['Nombre'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <?= form_label('Ciudad :','Ciudad'); ?>
            <select class="form-control" id="ciudad" Name="ciudad">

            </select>
            <?= form_hidden('oculto','valor_oculto');?>
            <?=form_submit('boton','He finalizado!','class="btn btn-default"')?>
            <?= form_close();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema, es que no me carga las ciudades del segundo select :S Ya lo he intentado todo, o bueno, lo que se me ha ocurrido u.u

Espero me puedan ayudar C: Muchas gracias.